# How to make autocomplete work in foreach php loop? (vscode, intellisense)

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, intellisense

I'm using vscode, and php extension pack (it contains mostly used extensions). I would like to use intellisense in this foreach loop:

```
foreach ($list_of_objs as $obj) {
    /* @var $obj my_class_name */
    // I want to go to definition of obj_method()
    //  with F12 but it's not working
    //  also auto-complete is not working
    $obj->obj_method();
}
```

Please give some advice, if you can solve this issue. I found solution for Zend Studio but not for vscode.

Is there an extension to support doc-block type hinting anywhere in the code? Would be really nice:

```
/** @var my_class_name */
$my_variable;
```

As far as I know, only place for variable types is in function declaration in php7. PHP IntelliSense also understands

```
$obj = new ClassName;
```

(bless them for at least that ...)

Comment: In PhpStorm, it works by setting `/** @var my_class_name[] $list */`

Comment: @NicoHaase In fact, PhpStorm supports both (and some additional combinations).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were trying good old [Eclipse/Zend type annotations](https://blogs.oracle.com/netbeansphp/defining-a-variable-type-in-comment-ii):

```
/* @var $obj my_class_name */
$obj->obj_method();
```

There aren't many editors that support them anymore. The de-facto standard as of today seems to be:

```
/** @var my_class_name $obj */
$obj->obj_method();
```

I may be wrong but I believe that [PHP IntelliSense](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=felixfbecker.php-intellisense) does not support either anyway (please try and report back). I can confirm that [PHP Intelephense](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bmewburn.vscode-intelephense-client) does support the latter.

Comment: My acceptance of your answer is sooo late sorry. But still thanks :) . It was a bit silly to not try other way.

Comment: And for completeness, in vscode, don't forget to set "php.suggest.basic": false in settings.json. It won't suggest you everything you don't need

Comment: Whoah, this last comment from @Kvader saved my butt. Kudos.

Answer (score 0):

As after a lot of search I did not find an easy solution for this, I came up with this working solution:

In your class create a static function

```
/**
 * Returns the instance itself for Code completion
 * @return ClassName
 */
public static function self($instance) {
    return $instance;
}
```

With that you can have an instance with type like this:

```
foreach ($list_of_objs as $obj) {
    $obj = ClassName::self($obj);
    $obj->obj_method()
}
```

It would be better if an annotation in the `foreach` worked but at least it is a way to use code completion at all.

Answer (score 0):

try this, it's work for me

add this to top of the foreach

```
/** @var post $post */
```

for example

```
/** @var post $post */
foreach($res_class as $post)
{
   // you can use auto complete in vscode
   $post
}
```